# Cloud Functions for Firebase - Is this similar to "Cloud Code" in parse?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

So after a break from Firebase due to some querying limitations and carefully selecting which features of applications I use Firebase for, I've decided I wanted to try to move one of my applications back over to using nothing but Firebase. With the new Firebase cloud functions this almost seems possible, but there's a few (two) concerns that I'm not too sure about that I want to have cleared up before making the fairly large move.

1: `Can I store information in memory for querying use?` I have a single query which requires me to query three fields, and because of this one query I've been forced into using a third-party server and managing a NodeJS implementation. I would like to use NEDB to sort a collection of necessary data to return user keys to the user on request. I've read that we can create an REST API with Cloud Functions, so it's mainly the data-in-memory that I have a question about. **Roughly 64 bytes per user**.

2: Can cloud functions run cron-jobs? I have some data that I like to keep maintained every 24 hours (at midnight UTC) is Firebase cloud functions capable of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Each function invocation should be expected to run completely isolated from each other.  There is no consistently available "shared state", which means no shared memory caches or shared local files.  This is the only way that the product can scale automatically.  If you need data in a Cloud Function, you have to find a way to get it, which could be some query.

2) There has been a lot written about this topic.  A search will do you well.  See the [sample code](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/delete-unused-accounts-cron) and [this Firebase blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html) for some options.  There is currently no natively supported scheduling mechanism, so you will need to build one yourself for now.

Comment: Thanks, looks like I'll still be waiting on more advanced querying support from Firebase before I can actually move away from my servers then. Unfortunate. Thanks for the answers!